# Does DNN Have anything similar to Views in Drupal or ACF in Wordpress?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

The company I work for is switching over completely to DNN. All of our websites were previously built in Drupal and Wordpress. I'm looking for DNN equivalents to Views in Drupal and/or Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress.

I did find this DNN extension, which seems like it will get part of the job done:
http://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-details/xmod-pro-46-forms-and-views-for-databases

Are there any others? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Try 2sxc content, I've started using that recently for customizing content types in DNN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNN have recently [announced that DNN 8 will include the Dynamic Content Creator API and modules](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/155187/solving-the-hard-things), through which the platform will support these sorts of custom content types (i.e. collections of fields).

Other 3rd party modules that are in that space include:

- [Form & List](http://formandlist.com/) (formerly User Defined Table)
- [2sxc](http://2sxc.org/) (formerly 2SexyContent)
- [Action Form](http://www.dnnsharp.com/dnn/modules/action-form-builder)
- [XMod Pro](http://dnndev.com/Products/XModPro)

We've been having a lot of success with 2sxc recently.  It's open source, actively developed, has good separation of concerns, and good portability.  We've moved away from Form & List because it lacked simple portability.  I haven't personally used the other two, but know that many people swear by them.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. DNN 8 is different from evoq 8, correct?

Comment: Yes, Evoq 8 is built upon DNN Platform 7.4 (the current release), and the next major DNN Platform release is version 8 (i.e. there will not be a DNN 7.5).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered Easy DNN News Module, and I'm liking it. It mimics a bit more closely the functionality of ACF in Wordpress. It's more bulletproof than 2sxc, which was susceptible to a lot of user error when trying to define content types and templates.

It isn't perfect, as I have to do some odd workarounds in the admin UI, but I wanted to recommend it here if anyone else was looking for something similar.

http://www.easydnnsolutions.com/modules/easydnnnews/overview